# Plotting a log scale graph with multiple CSV files as inputs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a graph from 4 csv files (each has one column of data) I have using matplotlib.
Each of these files should correspond to another line (I'd love for it to be in different colors too) on my plot, and I wish that the x axis would be in a log scale.

How can I do that?

This code works for me for 1 file:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

per_data=genfromtxt('/content/drive/MyDrive/mse_loss_noisy_image.csv',delimiter=',')
plt.plot(per_data)
```

Comment: What you want to do is read the data using `pandas` function `pd.read_csv()` which you can then merge with the other dataframes and then plot it.
We need more information about the plot you want, and the data you have in order to help you properly.
This is a link to pandas `read_csv` function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
And here's a link to merge dataframes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge

Comment: My data in each CSV is a colum of 11000 float numbers, where I want the y axis to represent each number, and the x axis is the iteration, like for the first float it would be 1, for the second - 2, and the last is 11000.

Comment: So after combining all the CSV files, you'd have one long column of all 4 files or 4 columns, each for each file?

Comment: I dont know if I need to combine the files, I just want each colum of each file to correspond to one line (graph) of the graph.

Comment: I provided an answer with what you want, the fact you wanted multiple subplots was unclear for me at the beginning but now I think I got it, let me know if not.

Answer (score 0):

After understanding the question better through the comments, I believe this is the code you are looking for:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("path_to_file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("path_to_file2.csv")
df3 = pd.read_csv("path_to_file3.csv")
df4 = pd.read_csv("path_to_file4.csv")
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], axis=1)
df.plot()
```

I ran this code with the following dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [20, 25, 30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [10, 40, 50]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'c': [5, 15, 35]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'d': [10, 25, 40]})
```

And got this result:

[image]

(the numbers on the x-axis are the indexes for each value)

I hope this is what you wanted, let me know if not.

Comment: Hi, the indexes on the x axis should be integers 1-11000.
And I need the x axis to be in a log scale if its possible sir.